# Declaring a "var" in a page in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC having developed in WebForms for a long time and I'm following an online course to update an existing WebForms project to an MVC project. Most of the things are working without a hitch but I have found one thing in my course that I just cannot understand.

In my course the presenter does the following:

CreateEdit.cshtml:

```
    <label>Description</label>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Desc)
</div>

var list = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem() { Text="Look at me", Value="1" }
}

<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category, list, new { @class = "form-control" }
</div>
```

Regardless of what I do the "var list ..." part doesn't work in my Visual Studio.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or why this way of typing doesn't work??

------ Edited with the full page included: ----------

```
@model CypherMVC.Models.Task

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">
            Create a New Task<br />
            <small>These are issues your team members should take care of - ASAP!</span></small>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEdit", "Task"))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Title)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 5 })
            </div>

            var list = List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Look at me", Value="1" }
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CategoryId, "Category")
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryId, list, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.DueDate, "Due Date")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DueDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.AssignedToId, "Assigned To")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AssignedToId, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.AssociatedMessageId, "Associated Message")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AssociatedMessageId, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Notes)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Notes, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 5 })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Completed, "Is Complete")
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Completed)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" text="Submit">
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a terrible code example, and that code belongs in the controller, not the view. But it needs to be wrapped in a razor code block - `@{ var list = new List<SelectListItem>(){ ... }; }`

Comment: what do you mean its doesnt work? Is there any console errors?

Comment: I understand that it's a terrible example and he only does it very temporarily to show the DropDownList function.  The thing is that he does NOT wrap it in @{} and it still works. If I open up his project I can also do it without @{} (in his project files) but it refuse to work in my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All C# code inside a razor template needs to go inside code blocks (`@{ ... }`). Here are the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor#razor-code-blocks) on this.

Your example should look like this:

```
    <label>Description</label>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Desc)
</div>

@{
   var list = new List<SelectListItem>()
   {
       new SelectListItem() { Text="Look at me", Value="1" }
   };
}

<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category, list, new { @class = "form-control" }
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: Since Mr.Glaurung says that the code from the course he is following is getting this to work without the code block syntax, I suspect the code is already inside a razor [control structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor#control-structures).

The code examples below would also work. Since we don't see the whole template in your example, we can't know for sure.

Inside a loop:

```
@{
    var someList = new List<string>() {"1", "2", "3"};
}
@foreach (var s in someList)
{
    <h1>Some HTML</h1>

    //C# code
    var list = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};

    <h2>More HTML</h2>
}
```

Or inside a if statement:

```
@if (true)
{
    <h1>Some HTML</h1>

    //C# code
    var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

    <h2>More HTML</h2>
}
```

Comment: See comment above

Comment: I suspect the USING statement in that case, could that be it??

Comment: @Mr.Glaurung - Yes, some goes for using statement. `@using(...) { //C# code here is OK }`

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap it with

```
@{
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
      new SelectListItem() { Text="Look at me", Value="1" }
    };
}
```

Comment: See my comment above

Comment: can you please share the full _CreateEdit.cshtml_